# My filter stops working when I add another layer of bitwise operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, bitwise-operators

- The data are available in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694704).

I've no doubt the solution's extremely simple but I'm stumped. When I apply the following filter to a dataframe:

```py
def filt(g):
return ((len(g)>=9) | (len(g)<=3))

milk_countries_exports_0401_filt=milk_countries_exports_0401.groupby(['Commodity','Partner']).filter(filt)
milk_countries_exports_0401_filt.groupby(['Commodity','Partner'])[['Trade Value (US$)']].aggregate([len,sum]).head(5)
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Where clearly len (in this case meaning number of months traded in) is either less than or equal to 3, or greater than or equal to 9.

But as soon as I make the filter more complex:

```py
def filt(g):
       return ((len(g)>=9 & g['Trade Value (US$)'].max()<2500) | (len(g)<=3 & g['Trade Value (US$)'].min()>250000))

milk_countries_exports_0401_filt=milk_countries_exports_0401.groupby(['Commodity','Partner']).filter(filt)
milk_countries_exports_0401_filt.groupby(['Commodity','Partner'])[['Trade Value (US$)']].aggregate([len,sum]).head(5)
```

Which is intended to return a dataframe of countries who either a) trade for at least 9 months AND trade less than $2500 for each month, OR b) trade for at most 3 months AND trade for at least $250000 for each month. Meaning like earlier, the output should consist of len values of no more than 3 or no less than 9, yet I get this:

[image]

Which only shows one example since I only too the first 5 rows, but the part of the filter regarding len seems to have been ignored, as you can see from the len of 6 for British Virgin Islands.
How do I get it to work as intended?

Comment: Don't use `&` or `|` use `and` and `or` instead. They are completely different.

Comment: @venky__ - in this case, the bitwise operators are correct over `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitwise comparison operators `&` and `|` bind more tightly than other operators.

Wrap your comparisons in parentheses.

```
def filt(g): 
    case1 = (len(g) >= 9) & (g['Trade Value (US$)'].max() < 2500)
    case2 = (len(g) <= 3) & (g['Trade Value (US$)'].min() > 250000)
    return case1 | case2

df_filt = df.groupby(['Commodity','Partner']).filter(filt)
df_filt.groupby(['Commodity','Partner'])[['Trade Value (US$)']].aggregate([len,sum])
```